# Where are QGIS application setting file(s) stored?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I have some application settings (Windows/QGIS v2.0) that I would like to pass to other users (such as those settings defined under Settings menu>Options>Rendering tab).

In ArcGIS they are stored in a **Normal.mxt** file located:

> C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates

I suspect in QGIS they may be stored in **qgis.db** located here:

> C:\Users\userName.qgis2

but I do not know for sure.

Where are these application settings file(s) stored?

Answer (score 4):

The settings on Windows are stored in the registry:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS\QGIS2\Qgis

As Jakob said, you could convert to using an ini file and start QGIS with the appropriate option to use it instead of registry settings.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a QGIS.ini file for your settings by adding --optionspath and/or --configpath to your QGIS shortcut.

See more here: https://nathanw.net/2014/02/24/keeping-qgis-settings-in-sync-on-different-machines/

Beaware depending of you setting, that your settings will return to scratch.

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: Link is alive !

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150529023238/http://nathanw.net/2014/02/24/keeping-qgis-settings-in-sync-on-different-machines/

Answer (score 0):

On Linux / QGis 3.28, I found the app config at `~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini`, plus a number of files one level up. There are no QGIS-related config files in the `~/.config` dir.