# How to check 'Only request features overlapping the current view extent' checkbox as default in QGIS 'Data Source Manager - ArcGIS REST Server'?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS Desktop 3.28.8 on a Windows machine. When I open a project, I always find the 'Only request features overlapping the current view extent' checkbox in 'Data Source Manager - ArcGIS REST Server' unchecked. Is there a way to change my QGIS settings so that it always starts as checked?

[This old question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93754/where-are-qgis-application-setting-files-stored) suggests that on Windows I should be able to edit a settings file in regedit but all that I see at Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS\QGIS3 is: (default) REG_SZ (value not set).

Searching 'ArcGIS' in 'Settings' → 'Interface Settings' allows me to enable or disable the menu option to 'Add ArcGIS REST Server Layer...' but this doesn't seem like a place where I can change defaults used on the tab.

Similarly, I can't find anything in the docs on how change this. Any ideas?